# JQuery Cookies: Trying to retrieve a cookie value

Tags: jquery, cookies, set

I am using [Jquery Cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) but am having difficulty setting and retrieving the info.

What I have so far is:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
        var cookiedate = new Date();
        cookiedate.setTime(cookiedate.getTime() + (60 * 60 * 1000));
        $.cookie("mycookie", "checked", { expires: cookiedate, path: '/' });
        console.log(cookiedate);
          alert( $.cookie("mycookie") );
              });
    </script>
```

But it just isnt working.

Can anyone help me out to find out what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery.Cookie handles the dates for you. Just feed it the number of days you want the cookie to be valid for:

```
 $(function() {
    $.cookie("mycookie", "checked", { expires: 365, path: '/' }); //valid for a year
    alert( $.cookie("mycookie") );
  });
```

P.S. Just in case you are using Chrome and are testing locally - Chrome doesnt support local cookies - Upload it to a server.

Comment: Thanks Chris, yeah the issue was my expiry date! Dont suppose you'd know a better way to set it to just 30mins?